# Star Wars set ID 2

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, star-wars

This part appears to be one side of a Wookie ship of some sort[image]

and these parts appear to be from one set but I am not sure
[image]

this appears to be an Imperial ship of some sort
[image]

and this is from a walker but not sure which one
[image]

and I have no clue on these next 3 but I am hoping that they are unique enough to identify what sets they come from.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Welcome to Bricks, trevluk.  We prefer to keep set-ident questions to one set per question.  You got a great answer already here so I wouldn't edit the question at this stage.  But for next time try to focus it a bit more.

Comment: Scrolling... scrolling... scrolling...

Answer (score 7):

The first picture is one wing of set [7959-1 Geonosian Starfighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7959-1&name=Geonosian%20Starfighter&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Clone%20Wars%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]

Those are actually two separate sets. I believe the two on the left go to [7678-1 Droid Gunship](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7678-1&name=Droid%20Gunship&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Episode%203%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]

And the one on the right is [the Vulture Droid from set 7751-1 Ahsoka's Starfighter and Vulture Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7751-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]

The Imperial-ship assembly is from [8017-1 Darth Vader's TIE Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8017-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). 
[image]

Those are the legs to [8014-1 Clone Walker Battle Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8014-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]

That is one section of [9491-1 Geonosian Cannon](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9491-1&name=Geonosian%20Cannon&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Clone%20Wars%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]

The two gray assemblies go to [7957-1 Sith Nightspeeder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7957-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]

And the last two pieces appear to be in dark red, in which case, they would go to set [8102-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8102-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).
[image]

Comment: wow, awesome, I really appreciate it!